# Output Message for multiple INSERT - mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How to know what row is successfully inserted when using multiple values in `INSERT INTO`. Example:

`INSERT IGNORE INTO (a) VALUES (1), (2), (3)`

and the existing value in the table is
`1`

so my problem is, to know what specific rows inserted and if possible the rows that are duplicate.

**Update:** When i use `INSERT IGNORE INTO (a) VALUES (1), (2), (3)` in my php page with `$stmt->affected_rows`, it returns `2`. I want to know that the value `2` and `3` are added and value `1` is duplicate.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?

Comment: `$stmt->affected_rows`, this is the format I used so far. And it just return the rows successfully added, but not the specific row...

Answer (score 0):

you can use `mysqli_affected_rows` function :

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO orders (name) VALUES (1), (2), (3)";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$rows_affected = mysqli_affected_rows($conn);
echo $rows_affected;
```

Comment: `mysqli_affected_rows` return only the number of rows added but not the specific rows added...

Comment: @EmmanuelDedel it return the successful inserted rows, and when you know your total inserted rows then your failed rows = total - successful